# swagger and spring boot integration throws ScannerException

Tags: spring-boot, swagger

I integrated a Jax-Rs Jersey (1.16) Restful service application with swagger. Application uses spring boot to launch. I see below exception when I run the application using **`java -jar my-service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`** and access the `http://localhost:8080/index.html` to list the JaxRs resources.

```
14:01:53,135 INFO  Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  com.company.automation.impl
  com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.listing       [http-nio-8080-exec-1] PackagesResourceConfig
14:01:53,435 ERROR StandardWrapper.Throwable                                                                                                                              [http-nio-8080-exec-1] [/]
com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.ScannerException: IO error when scanning jar jar:file:/home/suman/dev/projects/MyService/my-service/build/libs/my-service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/swagger-jersey-jaxrs_2.10-1.3.4.jar!/com/wordnik/swagger/jersey/listing
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.JarZipSchemeScanner.scan(JarZipSchemeScanner.java:82)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.scan(PackageNamesScanner.java:225)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.scan(PackageNamesScanner.java:141)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:80)
```

I build the fat jar using `gradle build` including `spring-boot-gradle-plugin`. I could see that `swagger-jersey-jaxrs_2.10-1.3.4.jar` was bundled with the fat jar.
What am I missing?
I can the run the application fine by other means i.e `gradle distZip` and extracting the zip content into a directory and run the application run script files created by gradle. But I would really like to run it using `java -jar` to avoid extracting zip contents step.

**[EDIT]** Is this a caveat mentioned in http://www.opencredo.com/2014/02/24/experiences-with-spring-boot/ under `Caveats` section?

Comment: I think I can safely say that this is nothing to do with the caveats in that blog. What made you think otherwise? On the other hand without more data, it's hard to say what it might be. There's a swagger example [here](https://github.com/scratches/jersey-swagger-demo) using Jersey 2. I am not so sure that Jersey 1 is worth the effort, but we can give it a try if you can share your code.

Comment: https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2085

Comment: @abalogh if you can provide this jira link comment as answer, I will up vote and accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a documented Jersey bug, see [here](http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2085).